# Ignoring Apostrophe in Regex

Tags: c#, regex

I have a simple Regex that looks for the words "won't connect" in a string.

```
(.*) won't connect.*
```

But I want to have it so it can ignore the apostrophe in case the user types in "wont connect".

Comment: you want to match the whole string except the apostrophe ?

Comment: I want it so it will not matter if the user types in an apostrophe like if they spell it as wont instead of won't.

Comment: Put a question mark behind the apostrophe to state that it's an optional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(.*)won'?t connect.*
```

should be sufficient, matches " **'** " 0 or 1 times

check the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/X4oL0y/1) here

Answer (score 1):

Your pattern:

```
(.*) won't connect.*
```

The `*` quantifier is *greedy* by default. That means your regex will go wrong with:

```
foo won't connect won't connect
```

See [demonstration](https://regex101.com/r/91UR3L/3).

If you add a question-mark behind the quantifier, it will be lazy, meaning it will match only as much for the pattern to succeed. See an explanation [here](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#lazy_solution).

Improved pattern:

```
(.*?) won'?t connect.*
```